# Extension .js files don't show up in Chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

When I right click on the icon for my extension-in-development and click Inspect Popup (or when I click the icon and choose "Inspect Element") and look under the "Sources" tab, my .js file is nowhere to be seen - only a long list of inspect-able files like apitest, devtools, json_schema, etc. I can, however, find the code through the Elements tab by following the link in the .html file, but that doesn't bring to anywhere where I can actual debugging.

I've also loaded the "Hello, world" extension that Google's tutorial provides, and when I Inspect that one, its .js file is right there. I can't imagine what I've done differently from the tutorial example to cause this.

It's Chrome version 22.0.1229.94 run in a Linux VM. If there's any more information I should be providing, please let me know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Type location.reload(true) in the console.

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html

Comment: Sigh... Thank you. These sorts of things never fail to make me feel extremely stupid.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question right,

Under the sources tab, there are two more tabs, one says Sources and the other says Content scripts. You need to click on the content scripts tab, and there you will find what you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention that - it's not there either. You do seem to have understood me correctly, though. It seems to me it should be very visible, wherever it is, since it's nested under the long string of gibberish letters that is its extension ID.

Comment: @Zhankfor Could you post a link to your extension?

Comment: It's not uploaded anywhere just yet - it's barely a few lines of code at this point... Come to think of it, could that be why?

Comment: @Zhankfor I am not sure, but I do not think so. Do you get any errors in the console? Could you send me the file?

Comment: Sure, I can send you the files. To where?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25193/discussion-between-stephen-and-zhankfor)

Answer (score 1):

Okay So I figured it out, simply click on you extension icon, and a little dialog will pop up, then right click on it and click on inspect element. You can figure it out from there I reckon.  (My other answer would be good if it was a content script, but this is a popup script.)

[image]